# Having trouble with counting two criteria with countif

Tags: excel-formula, excel-2010

I have two criterias in excel.

I was counting anything that is 2014 and grade k-8 using countifs: `=COUNTIFS(A2:C3,"2014",D2:E3,"Grades K-8")` but it seems to fail.

```
Year 1  Year 2  Year 3  Grades K-8  Grades 9-12 Teachers 
2014    2015            Grade K-8   Grade 9-12  Teachers
2016    2017    2018    Grade K-8   Grade 9-12  Teachers
```

I keep getting value error. Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: You have in your formula: "Grades K-8", but in your table you only have values "Grade K-8" without **s**.

Answer (score 3):

This should do the trick :)

In cell `H3`, which search for the criteria `Grade 9-12` and `2014`

```
=SUMPRODUCT((E2:E6="Grade 9-12")*(A2:C6=2014))
```

The SUMPRODUCT looks for all combinations given the two ranges and gives you how many times they occur.

[image]

Since you search row wise for one criteria and column wise for another you can't use countifs. Or more precisely, your are looking in a range that across both multiple rows *and* columns when you search for year. So you want countif to compare each item in that array against the item of another array.

Comment: While Wizhi answer is correct and accurate, it is performing an array calculation.  On Larger number of rows and columns (more criteria) this will at some point start to bog your system down.  The `COUNTIFS` function is faster and will also allow you to use full column references  without performance penalty.

Comment: Thank  you for you input Forward Ed, much appreciated :). I tried to see if you could use `COUNTIFS` as I aspect it's more "efficient". `SUMPRODUCT` has to perform way more calculations due to the array combinations it has to perform, which would be a disadvantage on large sets and more criterias applied. I would love to see a solution with `COUNTIFS`too :)

Comment: Glad it worked :)!! Please mark the answer as accepted so other people can see that the question is solved. Grey check mark under the voting buttons in the answer. Take care :)!! [Accepting Answers: How does it work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Answer (score 0):

Based on the layout of your data and that you are only looking in 1 column for the grade, and the years you are looking for is limited to only 3 columns you can use the following formula:

```
 =COUNTIFS(A:A,2018,D:D,"Grade K-8")+COUNTIFS(B:B,2018,D:D,"Grade K-8")+COUNTIFS(C:C,2018,D:D,"Grade K-8")
```

Basically the check inside the COUNTIFS, the multiple criteria are all AND checks.  SInce the mutiple columns for each year column is an OR, you need to check each year column individually.  You can use + like an OR operations and repeat the columns checks.

If you need to check multiple columns and combinations of columns the formula will get unruly and you are better off with an array type formula like Wizhi has for an answer.

[image: POC]